# Trigger Jenkins Build from Jira Xray Issue

Tags: jira, jira-xray, scriptrunner-for-jira

I am referring to [Trigger a Jenkins project build from a Test Plan](https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAY360/Extending+and+integrating+with+Xray+using+ScriptRunner#ExtendingandintegratingwithXrayusingScriptRunner-TriggeraJenkinsprojectbuildfromaTestPlan) from Xray docs to trigger a Jenkins build from a Jira issue. While setting up the Custom Web Item, what link should I point to? I have just copied the link from the document.

[image]

On REST Endpoint setup, I got errors on requestMethod, getResponseCode(), and getResponseMessage() methods

[image]

[image]

I am not sure if ScriptRunner execution history is also not showing full payload info.

[image]

Jira DC v8.9.0
ScriptRunner v6.51.0
Xray v6.1.3
Jenkins v2.263.1

Would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is due to the deprecation of UrlConnection class.
You should update the code to use the HttpURLConnection class instead. It could be something like this:

```
import com.onresolve.scriptrunner.runner.rest.common.CustomEndpointDelegate
import groovy.json.JsonOutput
import groovy.transform.BaseScript
import groovy.json.StreamingJsonBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response
import java.net.HttpURLConnection
  
@BaseScript CustomEndpointDelegate delegate
  
triggerJenkinsBuild(httpMethod: "GET") { MultivaluedMap queryParams ->
  
    def issueId = queryParams.getFirst("issueId") as String // use the issueId to retrieve this issue
      
    def flag = [
    type : 'success',
    title: "Build scheduled",
    close: 'auto',
    body : "A new build has been scheduled related with "+issueId
    ]
    
 
    URL url;
    def jobName = "java-junit-calc"                         // could come from a CF in the Test Plan
    def jenkinsHostPort = "192.168.56.102:8081"             // could be defined elsewhere
    def token = "iFBDOBhNhaxL4T9ass93HRXun2JF161Z"          // could also come from a CF in the Test Plan
    def username = "admin"                                  // probably, would need to be stored elsewhere
    def password = "fa02840152aa2e4da3d8db933ec708d6"       // probably, would need to be stored elsewhere
    def baseURL = "http://${jenkinsHostPort}/job/${jobName}/buildWithParameters?token=${token}&TESTPLAN=$issueId"
 
    url = new URL(baseURL);
    def body_req = []
 
    def authString = "${username}:${password}".bytes.encodeBase64().toString()
 
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection()
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST")
    connection.setDoOutput(true)
    connection.addRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic ${authString}")
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8")
    connection.outputStream.withWriter("UTF-8") { new StreamingJsonBuilder(it, body_req) }
    connection.connect();
    log.debug(connection.getResponseCode())
    log.debug(connection.getResponseMessage())
 
     
    if (connection.getResponseCode() == 201) {
        Response.ok(JsonOutput.toJson(flag)).build()
    } else {
        //Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND).entity("Problem scheduling job!").build();
    }
     
}
```

Comment: Thanks the inline script error got fixed but I still can't trigger the Jenkins build from Jira. Execution History details is still same and I am not sure about the Link I am using in Custom Web Item.

Comment: The Url is based on your jira rest api base url.. e.g. http://xx/rest becomes then just /rest. You may copy the url you have there and try it out in your browser. It seems that is working from the screenshot you have though.

Comment: Yeah you are right the link is working as I am seeing the Issue Key in Payload. I am also trying to narrow down where the error is and I have a question, from 'trigger_jenkins_build_restapi_endpoint.groovy' file 'password' variable has User API Token which I was able to generate and 'token' variable has Project Authentication Token value different from User API token value. How can I obtain "authentication token"?

Comment: When I substitute baseURL values and hit from the browser the desired Jenkins build starts.

Comment: I'm not sure from your last comment if you were able to solve this or not. username and password are the username/password of your jenkins instance. the "token" is the authentication token you define on the Jenkins project/job as detailed here: https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAY/Integration+with+ScriptRunner#IntegrationwithScriptRunner-TriggeraJenkinsprojectbuildfromaTestPlan

Comment: My bad I was not clear. I have not yet solved it. I have used my Jenkins username and password for login and for 'token' it's my user API token. In Jenkins Authentication Token field I have the same user API Token. Please see images attached in below links.

SR REST Endpoint -
https://gist.github.com/pgundlupetvenkatesh/365b27ca477d84a8850f00bc1a61ba4c

User API Token page - 
https://gist.github.com/pgundlupetvenkatesh/de381aa444767ee6cac9eb8090d9c74e

Jenkins Authentication Token -
https://gist.github.com/pgundlupetvenkatesh/32a13c24e6b074037964ee743a86863a

Comment: I got it working now. I was confused with the token value for Authentication Token under Trigger Build Remotely. I didn't know some random keygen would work for that and the 'password' variable should be User API Token. Thanks Sergio.

Comment: Great :) If you think it makes sense, I would appreciate if you could mark my answer as correct.